# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want this code printing out everything except the first element of the for loop. But I get an slice error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from openpyxl import Workbook

f = open(r'C:\Users\anilo\Documents\Anilo\Projekte\Python\Verben\Konjugation des Verbs machen _ alle Zeitformen _ Duden.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
html_doc = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

uls = soup.find_all('ul', class_='accordion__list content-column')[1]
for li in uls:
    konjugation = li.text
    konjugation_neu = konjugation.replace('1', '')
    print(konjugation_neu)
```

Output:

```
Präteritum
machte (mich/mir)
machtest (dich/dir)
machte (sich)
machten (uns)
machtet (euch)
machten (sich)
```

The line `for li in uls[1:]:` results into an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Does anybody know how to do the trick without editing too much of my code, because I need this for my interview project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that you pick a single element from your `ResultSet` with:

```
soup.find_all('ul', class_='accordion__list content-column')[1]
```

So you wont be able to slice it - Remove the element picking and add your slice like this:

```
uls = soup.find_all('ul', class_='accordion__list content-column')
for li in uls[1:]:
    konjugation = li.text
    konjugation_neu = konjugation.replace('1', '')
    print(konjugation_neu)
```

**Note:** *Your slicing will iterate all ul except for the first - in case it should only pick the first slice would look like `[:1]`*

###### Example

To really get each `<li>` in your `<ul>` while slicing it you have to add an extra iteration:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc='''
<div class="accordion-tables__group"><div class="accordion-table"><ul class="accordion__list sidebar-column dashed"><li class="accordion__item">Hidden title</li><li class="accordion__item">ich</li><li class="accordion__item">du</li><li class="accordion__item">er/sie/es</li><li class="accordion__item">wir</li><li class="accordion__item">ihr</li><li class="accordion__item">sie</li></ul><ul class="accordion__list content-column"><li class="accordion__item">Präsens</li><li class="accordion__item">mache (mich/mir)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machst (dich/dir)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">macht (sich)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machen (uns)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">macht (euch)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machen (sich)<sup>1</sup></li></ul></div><div class="accordion-table"><ul class="accordion__list sidebar-column dashed"><li class="accordion__item">Hidden title</li><li class="accordion__item">ich</li><li class="accordion__item">du</li><li class="accordion__item">er/sie/es</li><li class="accordion__item">wir</li><li class="accordion__item">ihr</li><li class="accordion__item">sie</li></ul><ul class="accordion__list content-column"><li class="accordion__item">Präteritum</li><li class="accordion__item">machte (mich/mir)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machtest (dich/dir)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machte (sich)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machten (uns)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machtet (euch)<sup>1</sup></li><li class="accordion__item">machten (sich)<sup>1</sup></li></ul></div></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

uls = soup.find_all('ul', class_='accordion__list content-column')
for ul in uls[1:]:
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        print(li.text.replace('1', ''))
```

###### Output

```
Präteritum
machte (mich/mir)
machtest (dich/dir)
machte (sich)
machten (uns)
machtet (euch)
machten (sich)
```